# Entity of type 'WorkflowFieldUpdate' named 'Document.Updates_delivery_date' cannot be found

Tags: ant

I am getting below error while retrieving the following compoent

> package.xml - Entity of type 'WorkflowFieldUpdate' named 'Document.Updates_delivery_date' cannot be found

Here is the package.xml

```
<types>
        <members>Document.Updates_delivery_date</members>
        <name>WorkflowFieldUpdate</name>
    </types>
```

Comment: The most obvious thing to check would be whether or not the field update name is truly correct. If you pull down the entire workflow for `Document`, it should be fairly easy to open the xml file in your IDE (or something like notepad++) and search for the field update. The `<fullName></fullName>` tags are what you'd be looking for.

Comment: You could also go to [Developer Workbench](workbench.developerforce.com) and select Metadata Types & Components > WorkflowFieldUpdate

Answer (score 2):

This is a known salesforce issue please take a look at [this article](https://tugce.github.io/salesforce/metadata-api/mdapi/deployment/2020/08/15/salesforce-mdapi-deployment-error-1/) that explains a workaround that can help you